# File Upload to share storage

Tags: files

I am trying to create a load balanced Drupal installation.  My setup has a shared storage that all the webservers can read write to.  At the moment I’m having trouble setting up the Drupal configuration at {mydomain}/admin/config/media/file-system/ to save our content to the correct file path.

The file path on the operating system that I’m trying to write content to is of the form:

\xx.xx.xx.xx\my\content\folder\

When I place this in the public file path I get the content written to the local path:

D:\myDrupalInstalation{mydomain}\sites\xx.xx.xx.xx\my\content\folder\

However I know the PHP has rights to write modify content on the shared storage because when I try the same path in private file path the content is written to the shared storage:

\xx.xx.xx.xx\my\content\folder\sites{mydomain}\allTheContent\

Which is what we require.

How can I configure the public file path to write to the same location?

P.S.  I think it is something due to the fact that the Drupal config page itself specifies "*This directory must be relative to the Drupal installation directory and be accessible over the web.*" for public path and "* It should be writable by Drupal and not accessible over the web.*" for Private.

Thanks

Comment: a symbolic link did the trick.

Comment: Great! I made it an answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

In a Linux environment, this is done for NFS drives by creating a symbolic link under your Drupal webroot.

In the Windows environment, you can also [create a symlink](https://superuser.com/questions/210824/creating-a-symbolic-link-to-mapped-network-drive-in-windows) to a network drive path (e.g. *\xx.xx.xx.xx\my\content\folder* ).

Comment: Drupal won't save files into a symlinked location. I am trying to solve a very similar issue when saving a file attached to a node.